# Postgres if else inside left join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `users` table with these columns:

```
parent_type (string, can be either `ParentGroup` or `SubGroup`)
parent_id (int)
```

and also tables `parent_groups` and `sub_groups` with id and name columns. `sub_groups` also has a parent_id that relates to `parent_groups`

I need to select all columns from the `users` table and join the table 'parent_groups', like this:

```
select users.* from users
if (users.parent_type === 'SubGroup') {
    left join sub_groups on users.parent_id = sub_groups.id
    left join parent_groups on sub_groups.parent_id = parent_groups.id
} else if users.parent_type === 'ParentGroup') {
    left join parent_groups on users.parent_id = parent_groups.id
}
```

Comment: You are only selecting columns from `users` and using a `left join`.  Hence, both queries will return the set of rows -- although there might be duplicates.  I might suggest that you ask a clearer *new* question, with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better way to do this in general, and changing the table structure may help as well, but you could do this with a [UNION](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-union/).  You'd have to make sure the columns matched, but it would look something like this:

```
select * 
from users
left join sub_groups on users.parent_id = sub_groups.id
left join parent_groups on sub_groups.parent_id = parent_groups.id
where users.parent_type === 'SubGroup'
    UNION
select * 
from users
left join parent_groups on users.parent_id = parent_groups.id
where users.parent_type === 'ParentGroup';
```

Comment: I get this error: each UNION query must have the same number of columns

Comment: @user3743266 - That's why I said you had to make sure the columns matched.  You didn't include the table structure for `parent_groups` and `sub_groups` in the question, so I can't do that for you.